# Problem with the for loop iteration variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, variables, iteration

That's the program code(missing some lines):
It's all about extracting a specific number from a specific string line, and finally counting those numbers together as a float number, and then dividing them by the number of times the numbers were found in every string.

The problem is that the variable `nc` doesn't count in the following code?!

```
fname = "files/mbox-short.txt"
try:
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print("No such a file, try again..")
    quit()


for lines in fh:
    if not lines.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    oline = lines.split()


    for number in oline:
        nc = 0
        try:
            fnumber = float(number)
            nc = nc + 1
            print(fnumber, nc)
        except:
            continue
```

[The file specified in the code](https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt)

Comment: `nc=1` is within the `for number in oline` loop.

Comment: You are setting `nc = 0` to 0 every iteration in the for-loop. Declare it outside of the for-loops scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put nc = 0 out of the loop, otherwise you are zeroing it every time

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot, I actually tried to put it out of the second loop, but I was still there under the first loop so it didn't work, but it now works after getting it completely out of any loop.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
nc = 0    
for number in oline:
    try:
        fnumber = float(number)
        nc = nc + 1
        print(fnumber, nc)
    except:
        continue
```